# Laravel Routing: Handling Parameters for Subdomains and Main Domain in a Single Controller Method

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

There are two groups of routes: for subdomains and the main domain:

```
Route::middleware(['language'])->group(function () {
    Route::domain('{subdomain}.vizit.loc')->group(function () {
        Route::controller(FrontSightController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('/sights', 'index')->name('subdomain.main.sights.index');
            Route::get('/sights/category/{category_slug}', 'showByCategory')->name('subdomain.main.sights.category.index');
        });
    });
});

Route::middleware(['language'])->group(function () {
    Route::domain('vizit.loc')->group(function () 
        Route::controller(FrontSightController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('/sights', 'index')->name('main.sights.index');
            Route::get('/sights/category/{category_slug}', 'showByCategory')->name('main.sights.category.index');
        });
    });
});
```

In the index method, I pass the $subdomain parameter, and everything works fine for both groups:

```
public function index(Request $request, $subdomain = null)
```

However, in the showByCategory method, there is an additional $category_slug parameter:

```
public function showByCategory(Request $request, $category_slug, $subdomain = null)
    {
        $subdomain = $request->route('subdomain');
        $region_id = $this->regionService->getRegionIdByDomain($subdomain);
        $categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')->get(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
        $regions = Region::with('districts')->get(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
        $services = Service::get(['id', 'name', 'slug', 'icon']);
        $category_id = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->value('id');
        $sights = Sight::where('category_id', $category_id)->filter($request)->where('region_id', $region_id)->latest()->paginate(20);
        dd($subdomain, $region_id, $category_slug, $sights);
        if (is_null($region_id)) {
            $sights = Sight::where('category_id', $category_id)->filter($request)->latest()->paginate(20);
        }
        return view('main.sights.index', compact('sights', 'categories', 'regions', 'services'));
    }
```

When I click on links for subdomains, the method behaves incorrectly because the values of $subdomain and $category_slug are the same in the blade template:

```
@if(!is_null($subdomain))
                        <a href="{{ route('subdomain.main.sights.category.index', [$subdomain, $sight->category->slug]) }}" class="btn btn-outline-weldonBlue">
                            {{ $sight->category->name[app()->getLocale()] }}
                        </a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('main.sights.category.index', $sight->category->slug) }}" class="btn btn-outline-weldonBlue">
                            {{ $sight->category->name[app()->getLocale()] }}
                        </a>
                    @endif
```

If I make $subdomain and $category_slug optional parameters in the showByCategory method, then the links for the main domain will not work.

In the Route::domain('{subdomain}.vizit.loc') setting, {subdomain} cannot be an optional parameter.

Is there a way to solve this issue without duplicating identical methods for subdomains and the main domain?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, in Laravel document about [subdomain](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing). The `$subdomain` is placed before `$id`

But in your `showByCategory`, you put `$subdomain` behind. This will make Laravel put the value of `{subdomain}` into your `$category_slug`.

Further, I can see you set

```php
$subdomain = $request->route('subdomain');
```

Maybe because when you debug, you see the value of `$subdomain` is incorrect. This line will assign `{subdomain}` to your `$subdomain`, which accidentally identical to `$category_slug`. Try to swap `$subdomain` and `$category_slug` positions.

Hope this suggest will help you.

---

I have a little test that might help. I've try this little block of code here

```php
Route::get('/{user}/category/{group}', function (Request $request, $group, $user) {
  dd($user);
});
```

When you access this link `/user/category/group`. The above code will return `"group"` instead of `"user"`

Why? Because Laravel will just put your route parameter sequentially. What come first will be put first. So in your case,

```
{subdomain} => $category_slug
{category_slug} => $subdomain
```

So you should try something like this

```php
public function showByCategory(Request $request, $category_slug, $subdomain = null)
    {
        if (is_null($subdomain)) {
          // This means you've access your main domain
          // Both will in the right place
        } else {
          // Else, swap their positions
          $category_slug = $subdomain;
          $subdomain = $request->route('subdomain');
        }

        $region_id = $this->regionService->getRegionIdByDomain($subdomain);
        $categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')->get(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
        $regions = Region::with('districts')->get(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
        $services = Service::get(['id', 'name', 'slug', 'icon']);
        $category_id = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->value('id');
        $sights = Sight::where('category_id', $category_id)->filter($request)->where('region_id', $region_id)->latest()->paginate(20);
        dd($subdomain, $region_id, $category_slug, $sights);
        if (is_null($region_id)) {
            $sights = Sight::where('category_id', $category_id)->filter($request)->latest()->paginate(20);
        }
        return view('main.sights.index', compact('sights', 'categories', 'regions', 'services'));
    }
```

Comment: The issue is that $category_slug has the value of $subdomain in case of subdomains routing :(

Comment: So if you click your subdomain link, your `$category_slug` will have value of `{subdomain}`, right? That because maybe Laravel will put `{subdomain}` value into `$category_slug` and `{category_slug}` into `$subdomain`. But you just change `$subdomain` into `{subdomain}` at the start of method. Have you try delete that line to see if their data is different?

Comment: `$category_slug` is right in the main route. But in the subdomain route `$category_slug` has the value of the `$subdomain`. If I'll make in the method likes this `public function showByCategory(Request $request, $subdomain = null, $parent_slug = null)` then subdomain route will be fine but main route will fail.

Comment: Sorry for making you confuse. I've edited my answer, you should check it

Comment: It's interesting :) But `$subdomain` never has the value of `$category_slug`.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case, my last suggest is clear both your `$category_slug` and `$subdomain`. Then retrieve them through `Route::input('category_slug')` and `Route::input('subdomain')`

Answer (score 0):

Made a little adjustment to the 'showByCategory' route for the main domain by allowing the {category_slug?} parameter to be optional. This way, we can use one controller method for both subdomains and the main domain

```
Route::middleware(['language'])->group(function () {
    Route::domain('{subdomain}.vizit.loc')->group(function () {
        Route::controller(FrontSightController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('/sights', 'index')->name('subdomain.main.sights.index');
            Route::get('/sights/category/{category_slug}', 'showByCategory')->name('subdomain.main.sights.category.index');
        });
    });
});

Route::middleware(['language'])->group(function () {
    Route::domain('vizit.loc')->group(function () {
        Route::controller(FrontSightController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('/sights', 'index')->name('main.sights.index');
            Route::get('/sights/category/{category_slug?}', 'showByCategory')->name('main.sights.category.index');
        });
    });
});
```

Now, in your controller method, you can handle the logic accordingly:

```
public function showByCategory(Request $request, $category_slug = null, $subdomain = null)
{
    // The rest of your logic remains unchanged
}
```

With this setup you can use the same controller method for both subdomains and the main domain. in your Blade template you can adjust the link generation :

```
@if (!is_null($subdomain))
    <a href="{{ route('subdomain.main.sights.category.index', [$subdomain, $sight->category->slug]) }}" class="btn btn-outline-weldonBlue">
        {{ $sight->category->name[app()->getLocale()] }}
    </a>
@else
    <a href="{{ route('main.sights.category.index', $sight->category->slug) }}" class="btn btn-outline-weldonBlue">
        {{ $sight->category->name[app()->getLocale()] }}
    </a>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it didn't help. `dd($subdomain, $region_id, $category_slug, $sights)` still shows that $category_slug has the value of the $subdomain